# Why new Contact framework in iOS 9.0 not offered kABPersonCreationDateProperty and kABPersonModificationDateProperty like property?

Tags: ios9

I am implementing contact list of iOS in an app. I want to support iOS8 and iOS9. But, I am facing the problem, the  AddressBook framework are deprecated in iOS9. I am using kABPersonCreationDateProperty and kABPersonModificationDateProperty in the app, in new Framework Contacts has not kABPersonCreationDateProperty and kABPersonModificationDateProperty property. Is any alternate available in new framework "Conatact"?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently these two properties are not implemented in Contacts Framework, you have to use the deprecated AdressBook framework (as mentioned [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/46912))